# How to Revert / Rollback a Edit Suggestion

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I [suggested an edited](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7542329) a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389970/how-to-locate-sql-server-dts-package-or-sp-that-uses-specific-database) to change the related tags.

Once my edit was complete, I noticed that the same edits were already made to the question by another user. My changes are currently under peer review and will be rejected.

Is there a way for me to rollback the edit suggestion to the question before it is rejected?

Comment: You can't; you'll have to sit out the rejection.

Comment: I've triggered a Community User reject by editing the last revision. That rejection won't count against you for suggested edit ban purposes.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters. During any Suggested Edits, in the Review panel, I can see that the total rejects are shown which also includes the rejects by Community User. Whenever a user reviews any future edits, will these rejects not give him a negative outlook when reviewing the edits. For example in my case, I now have a single approved edit and 3 rejected edits two of which are from the community user. I am new to SO and trying to understand if those stats play a factor

Comment: I'd not be too worried about that. Suggested edits are almost always judged on individual merit; only if you are making very foolish edits would a reviewer start looking at the stats, generally speaking.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Is there any plan to implement a feature where the user can undo a suggested edit like in my case? If not, is there a way to get the Edit rejected by the Community user so that it doesn't count against bans.

Comment: There are no such plans I don't think. It really doesn't happen often enough to be an issue.

Comment: Thats a shame. I guess that the situation hasn't changed over the past half year, as the same just happened to me.

Comment: same thing happened to me just now(put the wrong archive.is link in an edit because i pasted the wrong one from my copy manager), now i have to sit out the rejection instead of quickly rolling back my proposed edit