# How to rollback an edit

Tags: support, specific-question

I made a mistake retagging a question. I had multiple tabs open and accidentally applied the wrong tags to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707814/time-delay-for-a-process-in-unity-3d). I noticed this but it was too late; I had already submitted the suggestion. Unfortunately the suggestion was incorrectly approved.

Now I need to undo my mistake.

I went through [similar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274474/how-can-i-request-a-rollback-for-an-improper-edit) [questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289108/how-to-revert-rollback-a-edit-suggestion) on meta, and I suppose there's something called a rollback? I can't figure out how to do it though. Should I just re-edit the proper tag back?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback

Comment: @Pang I can get to that page but don't seem to be able to rollback. Perhaps only users with a certain amount of rep can do it?

Comment: Then try this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121819/i-am-not-granted-to-rollback-an-edit-but-could-i-at-least-easily-suggest-a-roll

Comment: Ah so its just another suggestion that happens to reverse the question to a previous state?

Comment: Seems so. I strongly recommend you to write in the edit reason that you're rolling back and clearly state the reasons for the rollback.

Comment: Only users with 2K rep can do an official rollback. With <2K rep, you would just ave to manually undo your edit.  You are better off asking someone to undo your edit in chat.